# Request Specific Per-App Post Privacy Setting

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

So facebook just implemented this per-app post privacy setting for all applications as announced [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/543/).

There doesn't seem to be any documentation of any sort on it besides that blog post.

I'm interested in explicitly asking the user for a specific setting.  Right now it appears to default to ALL_FRIENDS, but my app currently posts with a privacy setting of EVERYONE.

In fact, my application broke because of this change; I only discovered it through asking [this question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7225349/facebook-graph-api-overriding-explicitly-set-privacy-settings/7230965).

Is there any way to ask for a specific post privacy setting (in my case Public or EVERYONE) on login, similar to how we ask for all other permissions?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Facebook engineers?  Any answers?  This is sort of a big deal.

Comment: This is a big deal for me. It broke my app, with no warning. Other major apps like the Tumblr app are also affected. (I tried installing it to see if any large publishers had found a workaround; unfortunately right after installation privacy settings default not to allow public posting.) Asking users to manually set the privacy settings is highly annoying, especially as it is not possible to redirect back to a website afterwards.

Comment: I'm pretty cheesed off by it. Unprofessional of them. No warning, and worse, I reckon the change was rolled out in the Graph API before the UI, so for a few days, apps couldn't post publicly and the UI to let them do it wasn't available to all users.

Comment: "This is a big deal for me. It broke my app, with no warning."

To be honest, par for the course for Facebook API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after checking several applications, it seems that they've changed the default setting back to "Public" for new installs.  I looked at some Zynga applications and there doesn't seem to be a way to specify which level of privacy of the apps postings. (if anyone has info on undocumented features, it's Zynga)  I also don't see any way of querying to see what the user has set it to.

edit:  did a little more testing...  It seems that the default is dependent on the account.  It appears to be the same access as the default offered when you make a wall posting.